# Элемент hover не работает в ссылке.

Tags: html, css

Доброго дня, я не могу понять почему у меня не работает элемент hover,
Мне надо чтобы когда навожу на ссылку работает только со спаном
html

```
<div class="blocks_services">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="item1"></div>
            <span class="1">Product Development</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="item2"></div>
            <span class="2">Custom Software Programming</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="item3"></div>
            <span class="3">Mobile Application Development</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="item4"></div>
            <span class="4">Games Design and Production</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

css

```
.services-bar .blocks_services a 
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#121820;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align:center;
}

.services-bar .blocks_services a span:hover
{
    color:red;
}

.services-bar .blocks_services a .item1:hover
{
    background-position: left bottom;
}

.item1
{
    background-image: url("images/sprint_services_.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: left top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы картинка появлялась на спринте когда я навожу на элемент спан то есть на ссылку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так?

```
.services-bar .blocks_services a:hover span
{
    color:red;
}

.services-bar .blocks_services a:hover .item1
{
    background-position: left bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

css должен быть по коду "выше" чем html с элементами, для которых этот css предназначен.